BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a BeneficiaryBloc
I have defined all my blocs and injects them using getIt, now I want to call this particular event BlocProvider.of(context).add(GetMerchantCategoryEvent()); in the initState immediately the page is launched but whenever I run the app, I am getting this error that says BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a BeneficiaryBloc.
Here is what I did
    class PageSelectParish extends StatefulWidget {
      const PageSelectParish({
        super.key,
        required this.title,
        required this.payType,
      });
      final PayType payType;
      final String title;
    
      @override
      State<PageSelectParish> createState() => _PageSelectParishState();
    }
    
    class _PageSelectParishState extends State<PageSelectParish>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      bool loading = true;
      final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();
    
      //declare merchant category list
      List<MerchantCategoryModel> merchantCategories = [];
    
      //errorState
      bool inErrorState = false;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        // call get merchant event
        BlocProvider.of<BeneficiaryBloc>(context).add(GetMerchantCategoryEvent());
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        final tabList = [
        if (widget.payType != PayType.paygroup) ...[
          TabModel(title:'All parishes', child: TabviewAllParishesWidget(payType: widget.payType)),
        TabModel(title:'Favorite parishes', child: TabviewRecentParishesAndGroups(payType: widget.payType)),
        ] else ...[
    
          TabModel(title:'From parishes', child: TabviewAllParishesWidget(payType: widget.payType)),
        TabModel(title: 'Favorite groups', child: TabviewRecentParishesAndGroups(payType: widget.payType)),
         TabModel(title: 'ArchDiocese', child: TabviewDiocesanWidget(payType: widget.payType)),
        const TabModel(title: 'National', child: PageNationalGroup())
        ],
        ];
        return BlocProvider(create:(context)=>sl<BeneficiaryBloc>(),
        child: BlocListener<BeneficiaryBloc, BeneficiaryState>(
            listener: (context, state) {
              pp(state.runtimeType);
              if (state is GetMerchantCategoriesLoading) {
                setState(() {
                  if (merchantCategories.isEmpty) {
                    loading = true;
                  } else {
                    //isMoreLoading = true;
                  }
                  inErrorState = false;
                });
              } else if (state is GetMerchantCategoryError) {
    
                setState(() {
                  if (merchantCategories.isEmpty) {
                    inErrorState = true; //initialize inErrorState to true
                    loading = false;
                  }
                });
              } else if (state is GetMerchantCategoriesLoaded) {
                //complete refreshcontroller
                //refreshController.refreshCompleted();
                setState(() {
                  loading = false;
                  merchantCategories = state.merchantCategories;
                });
              }
            },
            child:Scaffold()


where you are navigating to this page wrap that arround builder.

Which type of builder please @MunsifAli?

Builder widget.

Wrapping it with a BlocProvider solved the issue

The error occurs, because the context of State<PageSelectParish> doesn't have access to BeneficiaryBloc. You are injecting it within build method and the context there is different.
You can fix this by moving the BlocProvider<BeneficiaryBloc> up in the widget tree.
BlocProvider<BeneficiaryBloc>(
  create: (context) => sl<BeneficiaryBloc>(),
  child: PageSelectParish(title: title, payType: payType),
),

and remove the BlocProvider(create:(context)=>sl<BeneficiaryBloc>() inside the build method.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
  // Remove BlocProvider<BeneficiaryBloc> here.
  return BlocListener<BeneficiaryBloc, BeneficiaryState>(
    ...
  );
}

With this change, your context within State<PageSelectParish> should also have access to BeneficiaryBloc.

I am getting this error when I move it outside of the build method @quoci The default value of an optional parameter must be constant. (Documentation)

what const do you mean??!
